# Excel File is not downloaded in IIS Server

Tags: c#

```
string path=Server.MapPath("../ExcelTemplate/DownloadExcelFiles/FacilitySetup" + ss + ".xls");
log.append("Mapped Path"+path, 100);
log.append("Start to SaveAs Worksheet", 100);
try
{
    ThisWorkBook.SaveAs("" + Server.MapPath("../ExcelTemplate/DownloadExcelFiles/FacilitySetup" + ss + ".xls") + "", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, missing, missing, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);


    //ThisWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, missing, missing, false, false,
    //    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
}
catch (Exception exceptionObj)
{
    log.append("Exception During SaveAs" + exceptionObj.ToString(),100);
}
log.append("Worksheet SaveAs Successfully", 100);
```

Note:

1. part of code sample is shown above
2. I am Trying to download excel file
3. File is downloaded in normal, but when i run same application on IIS Server excel file is not downloaded.
4. i maintained log on each line
5. i found during runing line ( saveAs()) normal execution is not going to next line
6. i.e. problem occurs on saveAs()

How to solve it?

Comment: How about telling us the exception that occurs?

Comment: BTW: Using Office on the server is usually always a bad idea. Try using products from Aspose or Spire instead to create office documents on the server.

Comment: Exception is not occurs but browsers waiting cursor is showing continuously during executing line ThisWorkBook.SaveAs(...)

Answer (score 0):

try without Server.MapPath as you already have the physical path

Comment: How do you know that? After all, these are *forward*slashes which are URL paths, usually.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a deadlock (and not an exception).  As someone said in a comment, using Office interop in a server environment is a very bad idea.  See:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 for a lot of information as to why.  Check out [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

I recently encountered a problem with downloading .xls files.  Explanation is here:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2123563.  Who knows, it might be a problem here as well.